# KafkaAvroDeserializer Issue

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, apache-kafka, avro

I am trying to desrialize a Kafka Avro message using Avro Kafka Deserializer. This code is very common and already in practice by lot of users. But I am facing few difficulties in implementing the same:
Code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "broker1:9092,broker2:9092");
props.put("group.id", "CountryCounter");
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
props.put("schema.registry.url", schemaUrl);
String topic = "customerContacts"

KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer(createConsumerConfig(brokers, groupId, url));
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));

System.out.println("Reading topic:" + topic);

while (true) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ConsumerRecords<String, ATPEvent> records = (ConsumerRecords<String, ATPEvent>) consumer.poll(1000);  //1

       for (ConsumerRecord<String, ATPEvent> record: records)  //2 {

            try {
                kafkaMessageInputStream = new ByteBufferInputStream(Lists.newArrayList(ByteBuffer.wrap(record.value()))); //3
                avroBinaryDecoder = avroDecoderFactory.binaryDecoder(kafkaMessageInputStream, avroBinaryDecoder);
                avroEvent = reader.read(avroEvent, avroBinaryDecoder);
                System.out.println(avroEvent);
                kafkaMessageInputStream.close();
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to process event from kafka, see exception details" + ex);
              }
        }
        consumer.commitSync(); //4
}
```

Now, here are the 4 issue:

1. I have to add cast, otherwise it will through an error as 
   `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<String,ConsumerRecords<String,ATPEvent>> to ConsumerRecords<String,ATPEvent>`
2. `Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable` 
   I have no clue why this? Can I do this? :

   ```
   List<ConsumerRecord<String, ATPEvent>> records = (List<ConsumerRecord<String, ATPEvent>>) consumer.poll(1000);

   for (ConsumerRecord<String, ATPEvent> record: records) {
   ```
3. `The method wrap(byte[]) in the type ByteBuffer is not applicable for the arguments (ATPEvent)` 
   This I understand, but how can I convert a class to a byte, is there any other way?
4. `The method commitSync() is undefined for the type KafkaConsumer<String,ATPEvent>` 
   Can I just use `consumer.close();`

Please provide solution for 2 & 3, and if possible explanation for 1 & 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Kafka do you use? There are differences for 0.8.x and 0.9.x

Kafka 0.8.x:

1. return type is `Map<String, ConsumerRecords>` (see http://www.webhostingreviewjam.com/mirror/apache/kafka/0.8.2-beta/java-doc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)
2. use `ConsumerRecords#records(...)` to get `List<ConsumerRecord>` for iteration (see http://www.webhostingreviewjam.com/mirror/apache/kafka/0.8.2-beta/java-doc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecords.html)
3. `ConsumerRecord.value()` return `byte[]` (see http://www.webhostingreviewjam.com/mirror/apache/kafka/0.8.2-beta/java-doc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecord.html#value%28%29)
4. Use `commit(boolen)` (see http://www.webhostingreviewjam.com/mirror/apache/kafka/0.8.2-beta/java-doc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commit%28boolean%29) -- `commitSync()` only available in 0.9.x

Kafka 0.9.x

1. return type is `ConsumerRecords` (see https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)
2. `ConsumerRecords` implements `Iterable` (see https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) Thus, you can use `for(ConsumerRecord r : records)`
3. `ConsumerRecord#value` returns `T` (with `T == ATPEvent` in your case) (see https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)
4. `commitSync()` available in 0.9.x

Comment: I have used Kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.jar, but still everything is working as 0.9, I don't see any change. :( Java -1.7)

Comment: Don't understand your comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I wanted to use kafka-0.8 because of the specific functionalities that I wanted to use, Since I was using 0.9 earlier thus I was not able to use the first three features(as you answered). But the problem is even after using 0.8 and removing 0.9, I am not able to use the above features. record.value is still returning ATPEvent Object instead of byte[].

Comment: Have a look here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example for more example. Hope this helps.